# Find the effective resistance of a complicated figure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

Please tell me what is the effective resistance between A and B? How to do it? And which resistors should I take as parallel or series?[image]

Comment: Hi Utkarsh and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Are you clear what series and parallel mean?

Comment: @JMLCarter no....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In series means arranged in end-to-end so all the current must flow throw all elements one after another.

In parallel means arranged alongside each other so some of the current flows through one element and some of it flows through the other.

Once you decide how part of the network is organised, you can calculate the overall resistance. You can replace that part of the circuit by a resistor with that overall resistance, and the behaviour will be the same.

Comment: It is against the site protocol to post the answer, rather than address the concepts. please delete that. It doesn't help students in the longer term.

Comment: I deleted, but I think asking this question is also against said protocol. I also see no problem in knowing the answer, as, in the end, I'd never leave an exercise undone because of that. But, hey, if that is really against it... I never read all rules here because I think this environment overdoes them.

Comment: Indeed it was put on hold after my post, so it seems you are not alone in that view.